# Rendering a UserControl in code rather than XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, rendertargetbitmap

I want to use `RenderTargetBitmap` to render a UserControl to a bitmap without having to write the XAML for it.  When I do this I get a blank image, am I missing a crucial step?

```
ValTool.Controls.VideoFisheyeOverlayControl vfoc = new Controls.VideoFisheyeOverlayControl();
vfoc.Width = (int)this.VideoContainer.ActualWidth;
vfoc.Height = (int)this.VideoContainer.ActualHeight;
vfoc.FieldsOfView=this.FieldsOfView;
vfoc.CountLines = this.CountLines;

vfoc.UpdateLayout();
vfoc.InvalidateVisual();

RenderTargetBitmap visual = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)this.VideoContainer.ActualWidth, (int)this.VideoContainer.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
visual.Render(vfoc);
var finalImage = BitmapFrame.Create(visual);
// Encoding the RenderBitmapTarget as a PNG file.
PngBitmapEncoder png = new PngBitmapEncoder();
png.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(finalImage));
using (Stream stm = File.Create(@"new.png"))
{
    png.Save(stm);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of UpdateLayout you have to call [Measure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.measure.aspx) and [Arrange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.arrange%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the layout done:

```
var width = VideoContainer.ActualWidth;
var height = VideoContainer.ActualHeight;

vfoc.Measure(new Size(width, height));
vfoc.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, width, height));
vfoc.InvalidateVisual();
```